# Why doesn't this function grab the data in my csv file?

Tags: python, function, csv

I'm trying to simply open a csv file, and print out the rows in that file.  When I pass the file as a string to this function, the output is the content of the string, not the rows of the file.

```
def _print_rows(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as opened_file:
        read_file = csv.reader(opened_file):
            for row in read_file:
                print row
                raw_input()
        opened_file.close()

>>> module_name._print_rows('first_class_profile.csv')  
['f']

['i']

['r']

['s']

['t']

['_']
```

Comment: Did you make sure you're user the proper field delimiter? http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents

Comment: Also, `open(filename, 'rt')` is more commonly written and understood as `open(filename)`- and also, you don't need `opened_file.close()` that'll automatically happen at the end of the `with` block... (you're actually closing it within your with block, so I'd expect an operation on closed file error)

Comment: You have syntax error your code, there shouldn't be a `:` on the `read_file = ` line.  Your code works fine for me otherwise.

Comment: As far as I can see, the code's not even syntactically valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the code you posted has errors I think you did not post your actual code.

Your `_print_rows` function is actually printing the characters in the filename, rather than the contents of the file.  This would occur if you passed the filename of your csv file to the `csv.reader` rather than the opened file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> filename = 'first_class_profile.csv'
>>> reader = csv.reader(filename) # whoops! should have passed opened_file
>>> for row in reader:
...     print row
...
['f']
['i']
['r']
['s']
['t']
['_']
['c']
['l']
['a']
['s']
['s']
['_']
['p']
['r']
['o']
['f']
['i']
['l']
['e']
['.']
['c']
['s']
['v']
```

Comment: I think that's the only way to get the single character iteration.  A csv file breaks rows at newlines, but I believe it relies on the file iterator to do the breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I found your code not even run because of syntax errors as others pointed out. Also, you don't need to close the file: the with statement takes care of that. After I modified your code, it seems to work:

```
import csv
def _print_rows(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as opened_file:
        read_file = csv.reader(opened_file)
        for row in read_file:
            print row
            raw_input()

_print_rows('first_class_profile.csv')
```